# What is the meaning of numbers here in dinner question?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In English Drama movie "The Remains of the Day", *Lord Darlington* asks Mr *Steven* (Butler) about Dinner:

> Lord Darlington: What are we at dinner tonight? **14**? **16**?
>
> Steven: **Twelve**, sir.

How to understand this numbers here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lord Darlington is asking Steven how many people will be having dinner tonight. He speculatively suggests 14 or 16 people.

Steven replies that there will be 12 people sitting at the dinner table tonight.